# SQL to increment on change of item in a sequenced list

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a SQL server 2008 table with the folling data in it:

```
seq | item
 1  |  A
 2  |  B
 3  |  C
 4  |  C
 5  |  C
 6  |  B
 7  |  D
 8  |  D
 9  |  C
```

I what  return a new column which is a number which increments on change of item, as follows:

```
seq | item | Seq2
 1  |  A   |   1
 2  |  B   |   2
 3  |  C   |   3
 4  |  C   |   3
 5  |  C   |   3
 6  |  B   |   4
 7  |  D   |   5
 8  |  D   |   5
 9  |  C   |   6
```

The initial sequence must be maintained. Hope you can help, Tim

Edit:
I don't what to update the table, just return the result set via a view or query. Thanks for all your efforts.

Comment: Whoops deleted my answer. Just thought this was going to be a gaps and islands one. Didn't pay attention to desired results!

Comment: Hi, What I am trying to achieve is to give each "Group" of items a unique ID when sequenced by the 'seq' column. i.e. the 'seq2' column is imcremented when the item changes. I think my first request is not valid so I will remove it.

Comment: Thanks Everybody for spending time on this. I ended up writing a simple piece of code to loop through my data set (or sub set of it) and change the seq2 based on change of item. As the sub set is small this performs OK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
declare @T table(seq int, item char(1))

insert into @T values
( 1,    'A'),
( 2,    'B'),
( 3,    'C'),
( 4,    'C'),
( 5,    'C'),
( 6,    'B'),
( 7,    'D'),
( 8,    'D'),
( 9,    'C')

;with C as
(
  select seq,
         item,
         1 as seq2
  from @T
  where seq = 1
  union all
  select T.seq,
         T.item,
         C.seq2 + case when C.item <> T.item then 1 else 0 end
  from @T as T
    inner join C
      on T.seq - 1 = C.seq
)
select seq,
       item,
       seq2
from c       
order by seq
```

**Update**

A version where seq is a datetime. I have added an extra CTE that enumerates the rows ordered by seq.

```
declare @T table(seq datetime, item char(1))

insert into @T values
( getdate()+1,    'A'),
( getdate()+2,    'B'),
( getdate()+3,    'C'),
( getdate()+4,    'C'),
( getdate()+5,    'C'),
( getdate()+6,    'B'),
( getdate()+7,    'D'),
( getdate()+8,    'D'),
( getdate()+9,    'C')

;with C1 as
(
  select seq,
         item,
         row_number() over(order by seq) as rn
  from @T       
), 
C2 as
(
  select seq,
         item,
         rn,
         1 as seq2
  from C1
  where rn = 1
  union all
  select C1.seq,
         C1.item,
         C1.rn,
         C2.seq2 + case when C2.item <> C1.item then 1 else 0 end
  from C1
    inner join C2
      on C1.rn - 1 = C2.rn
)
select seq,
       item,
       seq2
from C2       
order by seq
```

Comment: Great!! Thank You. However, can I further complicate things by changing the seq column to a date, but I still want the seq2 to remain an integer. Sorry for the change but I am trying to think of all the senarios. Tim

Comment: @Tim - Updated answer. If you have performance problems with that, I suggest that you create a temp table and populate that with the first CTE (C1) with a index on column `rn` and use that temp table as the source of your data in the recursive CTE.

Comment: @Mikael. This is great. I have tried to place this logic in a view, but it seems to get reformatted by the editor. I am a sql novice and don't understand the concept of temp tables, but I will try and learn this technique. Many thanks

Answer (score 4):

I think you want this:

```
SELECT seq, Item, COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY Item) [Count]
FROM YourTable
```

For your second query it would be:

```
SELECT seq, Item, DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY Item ORDER BY Seq) Seq2
FROM yourTable
```

But in your example there is some inconsistency with the value of `Item` "B".

Comment: Hi, thanks for the swift reply. I have tried this method and it returns the total count for all the items, not just the consecutive items. e.g. C would return 4 and B,2 etc. Thanks Tim

Comment: Close, but when I try it I get a count field of 1,2,2,4,4,4,4,2,2

Comment: Thanks, I get an error asking for a order by, If I add this to the partition by I don't get the expected results, The records must be returned in the ocorrect sequence.

Answer (score 0):

for first one

select A.seq,A.item, B.count from table_name A,(select item,count(item) count from table_name group by item) derived_tab B
where A.item =B.item

Comment: thanks, not sure I understand the syntax, can you explain the derived_tab please.